# Percentage of contribution of multiple factors to a single dependent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, matlab

I have a set of data (underway observation along cruise track) which includes one dependent variable A and three independent variables B, C, and D. It's known that A is related with each of the three factors, so I want to find a numerical relationship that allows me to express A by means of B, C, and D, and would like to be able to evaluate the relative contribution of each independent variable to A.

I'm aware PCA is the tool to use in this situation, and I've tried it in Excel, only to get a biplot where all four variables are treated equally as the same type of dependent variable, and variable A is used to explain those principal components. What I really want is to see how A behaves under the joint influence of B, C, and D, and I don't care how B, C, and D themselves relate to each other.

(I'm working in MATLAB.)

Comment: It seems that you don't need PCA at all, you need to regress A on B, C, and D.

Comment: My final goal is to be able to predict A with BCD based on what the current data give me. So I think I'll need the multivariate analysis to derive a relationship between A and BCD, rather than looking at A vs B, A vs C, A vs D respectively.

Comment: Yes, @Lin, this is still called regression -- more precisely, "multiple regression" with A as dependent variable and B,C,D as independent variables. My point was that your question has nothing at all to do with PCA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As amoeba wrote in the comments, this is a multiple regression problem and has nothing to do with PCA (see [Linear regression on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)). I here use the standard assumptions of a linear model with additive noise:

$$
A = b ~ B + c ~ C + d ~ D + k + E.
$$

Here $b$, $c$, and $d$ are the scalar regression coefficients for your three explanatory variables, $k$ is a constant offset, and $E$ captures everything that can't be fit into the other terms (the error).

In Matlab, to compute $A$ if given all the values on the left-hand side, one would write in matrix notation:

```
A = [B C D ones(n, 1)] * [b c d k]' + E
```

assuming that all variables are represented as column vectors, and that $n$ is the number of data points.

To solve this equation for the coefficients $b$, $c$, $d$, and $k$ for given $A$, you can use the [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
coeff = [B C D ones(n, 1)] \ A
```

This operator gives a [least-squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), meaning $A$ is determined such that the sum of squared errors ($\sum_{i = 1}^n E_i^2$ or `sum(E .^ 2)` in Matlab) is as small as possible. You can then extract the single coefficients:

```
b = coeff(1)
c = coeff(2)
d = coeff(3)
```

These coefficients are estimates of how strongly the variables $B$, $C$, and $D$ contribute to $A$.

---

Your title says that you are interested in a "percentage of contribution" of the independent variables, and I assume that you mean percentages of explained variance. The problem is that if the variables $B$, $C$, and $D$ are correlated (share variance among themselves), there is no simple answer to that question, because the variance of their contributions to $A$, which are $b ~ B$, $c ~ C$, and $d ~ D$, do not combine additively. Assuming that there are no correlations, you can compute those contributions like this:

```
var([B C D] * diag([b c d])) / var(A) * 100
```

which gives you a three-element vector with estimates of the relative contribution in percent of the three independent variables.

Comment: This is a nice explanation and good Matlab examples. +1 in particular for the backslash operator.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to my question! Sorry I wasn't able to get back to you sooner. I see the multiple regression gives me a linear equation in which A is expressed by means of B C D. This should work on my data set because A is supposed to correlate with those 3 variables linearly. Just curious, if A is non-linearly associated with BCD, will this method still work? Another question is that you mentioned the regression works well only if BCD are independent to each other. Does it still hold true if they are somehow dependent, even slightly related to each other? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lin, if the relation is only weakly nonlinear, you can still catch the *linear part* using regression. For strongly nonlinear relationships you need other methods, see e.g. support vector regression.

Comment: The regression itself does not have problems with independent variables that are correlated among themselves (as long as they are not linearly dependent, i.e. [B C D] is not singular). The problem exists only for *quantifying* their relative contribution in the form of *percent variance* explained.

Comment: Thanks, @A.Donda. I now understand how to compute b c d k, but how am I supposed to obtain E in the equation? Is it supposed to be a constant, rather than a column of numbers?

Comment: @Lin, E is a random column vector, and you can obtain an estimate by `E = A - [B C D ones(n, 1)] * coeff`. However, normally there is no point in estimating E. What you are interested in is the part of the data where B, C, and D explain variance of A, not the part that remains unexplained.

Comment: @A.Donda, in fact my further goal is to apply the relationship between A and BCD to other sets of data, where BCD are available, but A is missing (i.e. using the derived equation and values of BCD to predict A), so in this case obtaining E will be necessary. Now I input the command but can't get the value of E because the right side of equation are two matrix and their dimensions don't agree, so I can't seem to work it out. Do you have any advice on this? Thanks.

Comment: @Lin, the variables have to have exactly the form as described in the answer, i.e. A B C D are column vectors of length n, and coeff is computed as specified. Then the dimensions will match – I just tried it myself.

Comment: OK, @A.Donda, maybe I'm asking to many questions here, hopefully this is the last one: Yes, I managed too get a column of E values using your equation. But I guess what I really need is a single E value that I can use, together with coefficient bcdk and values of BCD, to predict A in a single equation. Is it something doable? Many thanks!!

Comment: @Lin, no, E stands for the data point-per-data point deviations of the predicted A from the real A. It can by definition not be a single number. Since it is random, the unpredictable part, it can also by definition not be used to predict. – At this point I'd really recommend that you post another question where you explain in detail what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @A.Donda, I will make sure to do that and we may chat further afterwards. Thank you for you time!

Comment: Hi @A.Donda, I've re-posted my question in finer details at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144737/establishing-an-empirical-relationship-among-environmental-properties-using-pca. Would you like to take a look? Thanks!