# Establishing an empirical relationship among environmental properties using PCA and Multiple Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, pca

So, this post is a follow-up to a previous question of mine asked recently ([Percentage of contribution of multiple factors to a single dependent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144085/percentage-of-contribution-of-multiple-factors-to-a-single-dependent-variable)), with more details on what I am trying to achieve with the data.

Generally I have a set of oceanic data collected underway during a cruise: temperature (T), salinity (S), fluorescence (F) and inorganic carbon (C). It is known that C is somehow related to T, S and F respectively. My goal is to acquire an empirical relationship between C and TSF based on those data, which can then be used in predicting C for a larger ambient area and analyzing the proportion of variance explained by each of the three environmental factor (i.e. T, S and F). I was kindly provided with the multiple regression method by @A.Donda in my last post, which assumes that T,S,F are independent to each other in order to correctly evaluate the variance contribution. But they are practically not completely independent. So I want to try incorporating TSF in a PCA model with the goal of deriving an independent set of principal components to express C and estimate the percentage contribution to C. (I'm working with Excel and Matlab.)

@A.Donda, please join the discussion if you can.

Comment: Hi Lin, interesting. Now, the first thing I'd recommend you do before computing anything is to plot the data, simple scatterplots for each pair of variables, have a look at `plotmatrix` in Matlab. Secondly, yes, using PCA you can solve the problem of correlated independent variables, but then you would have percent explained variance not for your original variables, but for the principal variates – how would that help you?

Comment: Yes, @A.Donda, this is exactly what I looked for!

Comment: Is there any suggestions on computing such a PCA model in Matlab?

Comment: I suppose that I'm able to get the correlation of C and several principal components, which can then be converted back to the original data and make it possible to predict C based on the derived equation.

Comment: Lin, *predicting* is not the problem, its only *quantifying predictive strength* via percent variance that's problematic. Are you sure you need that quantification?

Comment: @A.Donda, I probably stated my question in a confusing manner, sorry for that. But the ultimate goal is just to make the prediction of C using TSF. It's OK if they are computed into a set of principal components, as long as the loadings of these variables for each component is quantifiable, which is what PCA is able to give.

Comment: But what exactly do you need the PCA for?

Comment: Because otherwise I'm not able to get the equation that allows me to do the prediction. In the last post you showed me how to do a multi-linear regression, but two problems for that: 1. TSF are dependent on each other, which makes the estimate of their relative contribution to the variance problematic; 2. The constant E is not able to be quantified, so basically the regression cannot be used to predict the value of C with the set of TSF data. But PCA can give the equation between C and principal components, and the contribution of TSF to each component can be calculated. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I was hoping that it would give me an expression, something like: C = a * PC1 + b * PC2 + constant, so that if I'm given a set of TSF data, I'll be able to use them to compute the corresponding PC1 and PC2 (based on the loadings), then drop them in the equation and get the value of C.

Comment: But you already have an expression: $$A = b B + c C + d D + k + E.$$ That you cannot know $E$ simply means that the prediction is not perfect; that's why it is called "error". So in practice you use $$A_\text{pred} = b B + c C + d D + k.$$ PCs don't make any improvement to the situation. Using the symbols of the previous question, but you know what I mean.

Comment: Can you post a concrete dataset here?

Comment: I'd love to, but this site doesn't seem to have a platform that I can upload the data to. Where else may I post it?

Comment: I see what you mean, @A.Donda. I'll try this again on some "training" data, and then derive the equation without the error term for the time being, apply it to the "test" data and see how much the predicted C differs from the actual measured C. Thank you.